# How do I print values from a list in a given range

Tags: arrays, dart, arraylist

I have a list  `y = [6,7,3,9,5,4,1,0,9,2,10,16,13]`, I created a function that receives `(min,max)` values which is chosen by me and not the actual minimum and maximum, I want this function to create a list of the values between the min and max and that list should also include the min and max values that I passed. I tried this following code but it did not include the max value if I passed `(5,16)` the output would be `[5, 4, 1, 0, 9, 2, 10]` and I want 16 to be included, if anyone know how to solve this please help:

```
findSecondRange(int min, int max, List arr) {
  if (min > max) {
    print("Min should be lees than max");
  }
  var a = arr.indexOf(min);
  var b = arr.indexOf(max);

  Iterable result = arr.sublist(a.toInt(), b.toInt());

  return result;
}
```

Comment: The `toInt()` is not needed. Try `var result = arr.sublist(a, b + 1);` to include the last element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your current strategy of finding index positions in your `List` is not really going to be useful since your `List` are not sorted to begin with. We could then sort it but we could also much easier just go though the `List` and make a new `List` containing only the numbers we are looking for.

So something like:

```dart
void main() {
  List<int> result =
      findSecondRange(5, 16, [6, 7, 3, 9, 5, 4, 1, 0, 9, 2, 10, 16, 13]);
  
  print(result); // [6, 7, 9, 5, 9, 10, 16, 13]
}

List<int> findSecondRange(int min, int max, List<int> arr) {
  if (min > max) {
    print("Min should be lees than max");
  }

  List<int> result = [];

  for (int number in arr) {
    if (number >= min && number <= max) {
      result.add(number);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

We can, however, write this a bit shorter by using the [`where()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.5/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) method on `Iterable` (which `List` implements) which allows us to get an `Iterable` with the elements that fulfill a given check.

So something like this if you want your method to return `Iterable<int>`:

```dart
Iterable<int> findSecondRange(int min, int max, List<int> arr) {
  if (min > max) {
    print("Min should be lees than max");
  }

  return arr.where((number) => number >= min && number <= max);
}
```

And this in case you want to return `List<int>`:

```dart
List<int> findSecondRange(int min, int max, List<int> arr) {
  if (min > max) {
    print("Min should be lees than max");
  }

  return arr.where((number) => number >= min && number <= max).toList();

  // Or a bit shorter do the following which is the same:
  // return [...arr.where((number) => number >= min && number <= max)];
}
```

Comment: You could shorten it further with List.where, which was designed specifically for such filtering.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Yeah, you are right. A bit of a brain fart I got there. I have updated the answer. :)